# Android xml layout with list view and edit text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have an frame layout where I have a list and an edit text and the two buttons ,Its xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="317dp" >

  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

and the layout look like this:
[image]

I want to put the button entitled also with "button" above the list view then what changes shall I do in order to achieve this??

Thanks,Regards Talib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you really need the `FrameLayout`, but based on your request, probably this is more efficient.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: while running the code edit text gives me the error, why is it so?

Comment: log cat is :10-27 23:58:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(12056): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: Did you try to cast the `Button` to `EditText`? Make sure when you declare the variables, they have the same widget types as declared in the layout. `Button btSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`, `EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a linearlayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With output like this:

[image]

Comment: when i run it it gives me NPE in main activity

Comment: logcat is :10-27 23:59:48.334: E/AndroidRuntime(12945): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: could you post entire logcat? (add it to the question)

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```